# Can I generate an array based on url path?

Tags: php

I have a path like:

/blog/2/post/45/comment/24

Can I have an array depends on what I have on url, like :

```
$arr = array('blog'=>'2','post'=>'45','comment'=>'24');
```

But it should depend on variable passed:

```
/blog/2 should produce $arr = array('blog'=>'2');
```

Is this possible to create dynamic array?

Comment: did you try to explode and then to loop over resulting array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
function path2hash($path) {
  // $path contains whatever you want to split
  $chunks = explode('/', $path);

  $result = array();
  for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($chunks) - 1; $i+=2)
    $result[$chunks[$i]] = $chunks[$i+1];

  return $result;
}
```

You could then use `parse_url` to extract the path, and this function to turn it into the desired hash.

Comment: Good job. Function saved for multi usage :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to find the current path.

now, you can use explode and other string functions to produce the array...

If you need a working example, Ill try and post one.

EDIT:

```
$path=explode('/',$path);

$arr=array(
$path[0]=>$path[1],
$path[1]=>$path[2]);
```

or don't know how long it is...

```
$arr=array();
for ($i=0; $i+1<count($path);i+=2)
$arr[$path[$i]]=$path[$i+1];
```

Comment: I have path, I just need first param to be key, second value.

Comment: well, you can use explode and than:
$arr= array(

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example trying to solve the issue. This will put the arguments in the "arguments" array, and will contain each combination of key/value in the array. If there's an odd number of arguments, the last element will be ignored.

This uses array_shift() to remove the first element from the array, which then is used as a key in the arguments array. We then remove the next element from the array, yet again using array_shift(). If we find an actual value here (array_shift returns NULL when the array is empty), we create a entry in the arguments array.

```
$path = '/blog/2/post/45/comment/24';
$elements = explode('/', $path);

// remove first, empty element
array_shift($elements);
$arguments = array();

while($key = array_shift($elements))
{
    $value = array_shift($elements);

    if ($value !== NULL)
    {
        $arguments[$key] = $value;    
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Not really an answer per se but you may find http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php useful.

Comment: would have been a great comment though